# Check if string contains all required characters

Tags: c#

I need to import a number of characters in a string format with a comma and check if a string is valid by containing all of them. The string must be in a format like that "AB2345CD" . This is the code I have for now but i dont know how to check if it is valid by containing all of the input characters and every digit between 0 and 9.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace License_Plates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            var allowedCharacters = input.ToList();
            int platesToValidate = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            List<string> plateNumbers = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < platesToValidate; i++)
            {
                string plate = Console.ReadLine();
                plateNumbers.Add(plate);
            }

            List<string> validNumbers = new List<string>();

            foreach (var number in plateNumbers)
            {
                if (number.Contains(allowedCharacters.ToString()))
                {
                    validNumbers.Add(number);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < validNumbers.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And it always has to be in the format "2 uppercase letters, 4 numbers, 2 uppercase letters" ?

Comment: *with a comma* - your example doesn't contain a comma; where does it fit?

Comment: How about using regular expression when you already work with a kind of syntax or mask?

Comment: I have to check for multiple valid characters separated by comma

Comment: @atanascholakov dont forget to close the question by validating and upvoting the answer you want...

Answer (score 0):

**Check if string contains all required characters**

you could use the linq extension All:

```
        var allowedstring = "A,B,C,D";
        var allowednumber = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
        var test1 = "ABC0";
        var test2 = "AZ9";
        var allowed = $"{allowedstring}{allowednumber}".Replace(",", "");

        Console.WriteLine(test1.All(c => allowed.Contains(c))); //True
        Console.WriteLine(test2.All(c => allowed.Contains(c))); //False
```